# My Honda WR-V ran out of battery for a long time. Now nothing works

Tags: engine, honda, electrical, battery

My car has completely run out of battery power. After carrying out a transfer of energy to be able to start. It's not working properly, the multimedia doesn't turn on, the alarm doesn't work either, automatic headlight and even the fuel gauge doesn't mark correctly.

What can it be? and how can i solve it?

Answer (score 1):

No dash action indicates that battery power is not being supplied. That could be due to any or several of these causes:

- the car's battery is discharged
- the battery cables and/or cable connections or connectors are defective and not passing electricity
- the car's ignition switch is defective
- a fuse or several fuses have blown

I'd start with the battery. The most telling diagnostic would be to borrow a known-good battery and charged battery from a friend's car, put it in your car, and try it. Trying a jump start from another vehicle would also work.

If the car starts normally with another battery or a jump, then you'll need to charge the dead battery; if it cannot be charged, it must be replaced.

If the car doesn't start with another battery or a jump, then you should remove, clean, inspect, and re-connect both ends of both big battery cables. Then try starting the car again. If the car then starts, the problem was a bad connection or connections between the battery and the car.

If the car still doesn't start, then look for a fuse or fuses that have blown. Replacing a blown fuse, however, won't solve whatever it was that caused the fuse to blow in the first place. The same is true of a faulty ignition switch. In these cases, you'll have to go deeper into the car's electrical system to find out. Given that you're apparently a novice at this, you'll need help from someone who knows how car's electrical systems work.

Comment: the car starts, after doing a boost, i drive for the battery to charge, but half of the electronics don't work as alarm and multimedia.
I checked the fuses responsible, they were all intact.
the battery is new (the car is new). No oxidation on the terminals.Could it be a lack of charger?

Comment: @Lucaskr - If you've completely run the battery out of power and it has stayed that way for any length of time, you could have damaged the battery and it may not be charging. Everything you've stated sounds like there's enough battery to run the engine, but not the electronics.

Comment: @Lucaskr You say the car is new. If the car is still under warranty, take it back and let the dealer fix it.